# AngularJS ignores link function for "some" of multiple nested directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In Angularjs 1.0.7 and 1.1.5, if I try to have multiple directly nested directives, all with replace set to true, the link function gets called only for the bottom 2 levels, while for all top levels it gets ignored

[This plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hjNiSOR8g7nqsfXP3bAu?p=preview)  - as an example  - does the following for the directive levelThree

```
 - <level:three /> is replaced by <level:two />
 - <level:two /> is replaced by <level:one />
 - <level:one /> is replaced by <level:zero />
 - <level:zero /> is replaced by <div>LEVEL 0</div>
```

So levelThree gets eventually resolved into <div>LEVEL 0</div>

Reason why I'm doing this is because I want to have at levelZero a very basic/abstract component that is customized by higher level directives. The only problem is that the link function is called only for levelZero and levelOne (You can see in console output), while for levelTwo and levelThree is being ignored. Is that somehow an expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because you're using `replace`, and there is no extra DOM in your upper level templates, so the nested directive structure is somehow lost in the compiling process. It seems to be a bug, but I'm not 100% sure.

But to workaround it is quite easy. In your template 1, 2 and 3, try to wrap `<level:n></level:n>` in a div. For example, template2.html is changed to:

```
<div>
    <level:one></level:one>
    <!-- optional extra stuff goes here. -->
</div>
```

The div wrapper might seem to be unnecessary; but in practice, I think you **will** have the "extra stuff" part in your template, and angular template has the `single root` restriction, so you will eventually end up having a wrapper as the root element of you template.

Comment: The workaround works, but in this case, I end up with div>div>div>div and attributes are not going to be automatically traversed all the way down to the bottom level.

Comment: As I explained in the answer, nested div is necessary to reflect the nested directive structure. You don't have any attribute in your plunk, can you explain what you mean by "automatically traversed all the way down"?

Comment: I updated the plunk with an attribute. As you see it's set on levelThree, and because the nested directives are getting replaced, the attribute is traversed all the way down to levelZero where it's being used.

The div is in fact necessary to reflect the nested directives as you say, however, having replace = true makes it nested only in declaration. while on execution they replace each other and no traces of being nested is visible in end result. This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, and this would make attributes automatically traverse as I updated in the plunk

Comment: Adding divs inbetween would disable this feature

Comment: Updated plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/4REs4dGKkPlVKJED78CQ. I made directives in each upper level *explicitly* hand the attribute down to lower level. IMHO, explicit is better than relying on the magical and implicit directive compilation process.

Comment: Well I guess you are right, explicit would be better, although I still hate it being resolved into several nested divs. The whole thing looks like a bug to me too. Thanks for your help.